# Create a middleware to verify a response object before sending the response

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm building a small CRUD app on the Express framework. I want to have a middleware that takes all my responses and verifies them against the expected object schemas. The issue what I'm currently facing is that I don't know where to put this middleware. I've tried to put it globally after my routes and the error handler middleware, but it didn't work for some reason. When I sticked it before my defined routes this middleware worked, but didn't have the required data from a route handler. I'm pretty familiar with the middleware concept in Express, but only for requests.

If you don't have a specific answer for this issue, please feel free to share your opinion if it helps to verify all outbound response. Thanks.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the relevant code so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.  Middleware has to go BEFORE any routes that want to benefit from the work it has already done as routes/middleware are matched and executed in the order declared.  If putting it before creates some problem, then you have to show us the code and explain the problem so we can help.  Questions about code here should include the relevant code.  We can help faster and more accurately and more specifically when we can see the code.

Comment: If you're trying to verify something your server is sending OUT, then that is not a job for middleware as middleware works on arriving data.  That's a job for a common function that you manually call in any route that wants to verify it's own output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you an example usage. You can modify the `response` object as you desire.

```
// ResponseHandler.js
// Creating a response object
class ResponseHandler{
    constructor(statusCode, body, success = 1){

      this.statusCode = statusCode;
      this.body = body;
      this.body.success = success ? success : (statusCode == 200 ? 1 : 0);
    }
  }
  
  module.exports = ResponseHandler;


// responseHandler.js
const ResponseHandler = require('./ResponseHandler');

const responseValidator = (err, req, res, next) => {
  let res = res;
  if (!(res instanceof ResponseHandler)) {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode;
    const body = res.body;
    const success = res.body.success;
    res = new ResponseHandler(statusCode, body, success);
  }

  next(res);
};

const responseHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {

    const response = responseValidator(res);

    res.status(response.statusCode).send(response.body);
};

module.exports = {
    responseHandler
};

// Usage

// In index.js (After defining your routes)
app.use(responseHandler);

// In controller
let res = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
        success: 1, // Optinal
        message: "This is a success message."
    }
}
return next(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. I was able to resolve my problem. I just had to add the err param to my middleware.